# Read-only SVN on Apache2 under Windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, apache-2.2, svn

How can I setup write access policies for an `SVN` repository under `Apache2` on `Windows Server 2008`? Please help. TIA!

**Update1:**

I have next configuration already:

```
<Location /svn>
   SVNParentPath "E:\SVN"

   DAV svn
   SVNListParentPath on
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Subversion repositories"
   Require valid-user

   AuthUserFile svn-auth.txt
   #AuthzSVNAccessFile svn-acl.txt
</Location>
```

File `D:\Program Files (x86)\Apache 2.2\svn-auth.txt` created with `htpasswd` and looks like this:

```
foobar:$apr1$cV5.....$iwiJXkY6qlKopphUxlPMM/
```

All works fine.

File `D:\Program Files (x86)\Apache 2.2\svn-acl.txt` looks looks this:

```
[groups]
full = foobar

[/]
@full = rw
* = r
```

And when I uncommented `AuthzSVNAccessFile svn-acl.txt` I got

```
403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /svn/ on this server.
```

Here is an error.log record:

```
The URI does not contain the name of a repository.  [403, #190001]
```

I need next directories hierarchy:

`E:\SVN` is a root directory for all repositories - I want to list the all. It contains `E:\SVN\test` - is a project repository.

and `E:\SVN\foobar` - is a sub-root directory containing `E:\SVN\foobar\foo` and `E:\SVN\foobar\bar` - project repositories.

Comment: can you remove "SVNListParentPath on" from your config and try to access it again + post error result if it still does not work?

Comment: can you list files you've got in e:\svn ; can you check if user under which apache runs has full access to the files? ; can you paste your config file again ; just for testing - can you put <Location /svn2/>  instead of <Location /svn> and use in the svn client http://localhost/svn2/ [ with the slash at the end ]

Comment: aa - and for checking - just use the web-browser. not svn client.

Comment: @pQd: All configurations work perfectly without specifying AuthzSVNAccessFile. http://localhost/svn/ lists directories of e:\svn. Changing Location in conf to svn2 moves it to http://localhost/svn2/. Without file works fine, with - error 403

Comment: ok, but change just Location to /svn2 ; restart apache ; try with msie http://localhost/svn2/ [ exactly like that! ], and provide the error log.

Comment: a yeah - and pls use SVNPath NOT svnparentpath and report the result.

Comment: Oh! o_O Works! SVNPath to specific repository works! under /svn2 or /svn. Thanks!! But obsoletely incomprehensible! How can I allow directory listing with SVNParentPath?

Comment: well - describe what's your objective. multiple repositories?

Comment: I want /svn pointing e:\svn and listing all directories there - each is a repository. I want to grant everyone RO, and specific group RW to all repositories.

Comment: Maybe I should not configure /svn as DAV? And should just as a directory with allowed listing?

Comment: in fact i've never used such setup - so i cannot really advice how to approach it. if you have small number of repositories - just make static html page with choice of them and put separate <Location..> for each. ugly... but will work.

Comment: Yea, it's easy but ugly.. I have a solution like this on my IIS7+DAV and ftp web acces. But there all directories are virtual. And here - real, under e:\svn so I'm looking for correct solution

Comment: can you post whole apache vhost config? is e:\svn also documentroot?

Comment: The rest of config is default. Nothing more. Only a number of Locations for SVN. DocumentRoot with /htdocs/ as a stub. Everything goes under virtual /svn directory

Comment: hm.. try adding slash after your svn in Location - change it to <Location /svn/> ... does it help?

Comment: [ via http://www.svnforum.org/2017/viewtopic.php?t=6443 ]

Comment: perheps we should cleanup all the comment mess

Comment: hmm.. I don't think it's really necessary. But if you do - ok, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding slash after your svn in Location - change it from

```
<Location /svn>
```

to

```
<Location /svn/>
```

not really intuitive, found via [this](http://svnforum.org/2017/viewtopic.php?t=6443) forum post.

Comment: lol; but it's done.

Answer (score 2):

to set up anonymous read-only svn access put in your vhost config for apache:

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /somewhere/svn
    <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
```

svn with authentication / write access restrictions - take a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/41382/setting-up-svn-server-for-multiple-users-over-http/41507#41507).

you can find more details in the '[version control with subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)', in [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) chapter.

Comment: Thanks! I found some information already. But it doesn't work.. After I added AuthzSVNAccessFile svn-acl.txt login attempt returns 404 Forbiden. See more in my OP

Comment: @abatishchev - did you tried putting full path to both txt files? what do you have in error.log of apache?

Comment: @dQd: sorry, what do you mean 'full path to box txt files'? What and where?

Comment: @abatishchev - i mean write in your apache full path to svn-auth.txt and svn-acl.txt ; and include here content of error.log [ probably in rootOfApach/logs/error.log ]